Are dissociation and meditation related?
Definitions for dissociation were discussed in this question.
Meditation can also involve detachment from the body and thought processes, ignoring of physical stimuli with some traditions having concepts like Nirvana which seem to relate to a cessation of attachments.
How if at all are those concepts related?
Is there any work which compares and contrasts these concepts?

They are conceptually related to the notion of a loss of sense of self but differ in terms of their affective properties. More precisely, depersonalization, a form of dissociation can produce dysphoria and a result of loss of sense of control. In contrast, meditation can produce euphoria and greater control. This paper describes and argues these distinctions in an active inference account of dissociation.
https://www.frontiersin.org/journals/psychology/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2020.539726/full
